# USB mass-storage corrupt on portable Linux device – fixing it using Windows CHKDSK?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-8, usb-storage, kindle

Due to some circumstances I forcefully shut down my Kindle DX (in fact, a Linux machine), holding the power switch for 15 seconds. I believe no processing or obvious file transfers were in progress there, but after reconnecting its USB to PC, Windows indicates damaged USB storage drive and displays request to fix it:

[image]

Currently, attempt of uploading files always leads to transfer interruption so the filesystem structure must be damaged somehow, it is *not a almost-false alarm* (which you get if you unplug the device without prior ejecting it). Attempts to properly eject the device have no effect this time, the problem remains.

**Is it safe to proceed using Windows repair or should I prefer some Linux tools for this Linux storage? Or they are equivalent?**

I'd like to add that I recently jailbroke this device (and [turned it into e-ink PC display](http://www.pcworld.com/article/259582/how_to_use_a_kindle_dx_as_a_pc_display.html)) so also **I am able to execute its Linux shell commands via *telnet*** (like shown in the linked article). Perhaps repairing the drive using the console is the first option I should try? Or is comfortable Windows single-click repair just fine?

Comment: "(which you get if you unplug the device without prior ejecting it)" - Those warnings are not `false alarms` those are possible alarms since what has happen often DOES happen by not properly ejecting the device.  Before I can provide an answer to this question I need you to define "good enough" to me.  I don't use subjective terms like "good enough" personally.

Comment: @Ramhound – 24 hrs later: still waiting for the answer you promised. (Currently I can see only answer from Ben Cook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have verified that drive type is FAT, so finally I'm going to fix it using Windows.**

Steps I used to discover and confirm filesystem type are highlighted green (click the image to zoom):

[image]

1. The `mount` command revealed there is a VFAT filesystem mounted as `/mnt/base-us` directory (see yellow highlight at the bottom of its output).
2. Then `ls` command displayed the content of the directory and it is what is presented as USB storage to Windows. So now this drive can be safely (and **preferably**, because it is Microsoft technology) fixed by Windows, simply by clicking `Repair drive` button shown in the question.